# vimeo full-window size embed

Tags: css, embed, vimeo

I am trying to embed [this](http://player.vimeo.com/video/66447127) video on this virb page: http://www.amytdatta.com (password: tyma)

It's an album pre-release, hence the site password, sorry!

Try as I might, i'm unable to emulate the full window scaling behaviour of the vimeo video page. I've tried putting `min-width: 100%, min-height: 100%, max-height: 100%` everywhere but my embedded video is taller than the browser window and doesn't scale in the neat way the vimeo page does.

any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within your CSS properties.

If you take a look at the following codesegment (base.css, line 208):

```css
#main-content .content-editor .video-container {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
```

You will see that you have a padding at the bottom aswell as a defined position. Just delete those two lines, so it looks like this:

```css
#main-content .content-editor .video-container {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

It'll look like you want it to.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you only deleted those two lines? If you take a look at the following screenshot you can see what it did for me: [/Amyt Datta](http://cdn.imghack.se/images/64a4d5571dd10eab008899ca4f5a6a8c.png)
And what exactly do you mean by "it went nuts?" :)

Comment: Maybe i'd accidently changed other things because the bottom of the video was peeking out from under the top margin of the browser window! Now i've reset everything and only applied your overrides (can't delete CSS using Virb) and I have this result: https://imageshack.us/a/img341/64/screenshot20130604at838.png I still have to scroll down to see the playbar at the bottom of the video, and I still have that gray area underneath. On the vimeo embed direct link: http://player.vimeo.com/video/66447127 the playbar is always visible no matter what the size of the window is. The video scales instead.

Comment: I've changed my goals a bit. I've added a line of text links beneath my video and now want to center and scale the video + the text in the browser window. Any tips would much greatly appreciated. Thanks! Site is here: http://amytdatta.com (password: tyma)